# UserControl in an HTML Document

Tags: html, wpf

Is it possible to use a WPF User Control (or a Page) in an HTML Document? Not a web server, but a simple stand-alone HTML document.

What I am trying to do is create a simple WPF Page, host it in an HTML document and have the HTML document be the custom view for an Outlook Folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.  what you **CAN** do is host a WPF app in a browser.  [here is a bit of MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx).  Now, that said, it can be complex and problematic to do this--what with security models,browser certificates,  etc.  if you can do what you want w/o using an XBAP then I would recommend doing so... there are easier ways (like silverlight) to do alot of the same things that WPF does.

Answer (score 0):

Like WPF, **Silverlight** uses XAML, but they are different flavors of XAML.

So, you have the start of a Silverlight app, if you want to convert it. Keeping the two versions synchronized could be a challenge.

This posting tells you [How to convert WPF Application in Silverlight](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/2870.aspx/1), and you can probably find more information if you decide to follow this path.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly in a basic HTML document. If you are familiar with WPF and wish to extend your skills to web development I recommend you look into developing web applications with Silverlight. WPF desktop development, Windows Phone development and Silverlight web development are all very similar and from personal experience I can tell you that the transition from one to another is easy.

If you aren't yet familiar with WPF but want to add more functionality to your webpages you might also want to look into developing with ASP.NET, which gives you more functionality than basic HTML, but at the same time might be less daunting to learn if you haven't yet delved into WPF as it more closely resembles HTML.

Comment: I can host it in an ASP.NET page but all I want to do is have a simple HTML document hold the WPF app. This is not meant to be hosted on a website at all, the HTML page is to act as a shell for the WPF app since that is the only way to display my app (The way I want it, i.e. to replace the folder view and reading pane) in Outlook.

Comment: To my knowledge the only way to integrate WPF into an HTML document is through Silverlight. That doesn't mean it is outright impossible however, so perhaps somebody else can give you a workaround that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

XAML and HTML are both XML but not the same and not interchangeable.  A BrowserControl will display HTML (not XAML).   Your concept that HTML will hold WPF is wrong.   XBAP is an application the runs in the browser but it is not simply XAML in HTML.  If you want the user to interact with a custom view of an Outlook folder then the WPF TreeView control is probably a better fit.